# How to exclude css files inside "node_modules" with webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

In a very simple demo of my javascript project, I use "css-loader" to load css files.

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './entry.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: path.resolve('./node_modules/'),
            use: [
                {loader: 'style-loader'},
                {loader: 'css-loader'}
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

Please notice I have already exclude "node_modules" dir.

But when I run `npx webpack`, the output

```
Hash: 3d4b3f13f73f8b4ff12f
Version: webpack 4.17.1
Time: 255ms
Built at: 2018-09-12 18:13:34
    Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  23 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = bundle.js
[./entry.js] 78 bytes {main} [built]
[./index.css] 1.04 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./index.css] ./node_modules/css-loader!./index.css 196 bytes {main} [built]
    + 3 hidden modules
```

still contains something about "node_modules".

I can't find where is the problem, how to fix it?

Update:

I make a demo for this question: https://github.com/freewind-demos/javascript-webpack-exclude-node-modules-issue-demo
 , you can clone and try with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit misunderstanding here. **Webpack** by itself only knows javascript,  when it needs to compile other resources like .css, .scss, etc. We use respective loader to compile these non javascript resources.

What actually happens here webpack uses `css-loader` (node module) to compiles all css files in our tree, starting from entry point. It first convert into string using a util in  `index.js` of css-loader :

```
loaderUtils.stringifyRequest(this, require.resolve("./css-base.js")) // line 153 css-loader/lib/loader.js
```

---

```
[./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./index.css] ./node_modules/css-loader!./index.css 196 bytes {main} [built]
```

The line above explaining how css loader compiles and bundles css code of your `index.css` found at in the `entry.js`. The point here is, these files are not redundant,  they are helping webpack in bundling non js files. Although webpack generated output is little bit confusing but still I would recommend to study the source code of `css-loader` where it gives you understandable concept how it is compiling css to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need `path.resolve` . Resplce  `exclude: path.resolve('./node_modules/')` with

`exclude:/node_modules/` . `path.resolve` will require `__dirname`

Comment: @br Thanks, but `exclude: /node_modules/` doesn't work neither. It gives exactly the same output.

Comment: I also added a demo project, appended in the question